# How to use the display (e.g. a browser) when sudo-ed into root or another user

Tags: xorg, firefox, sudo, gksudo

When I sudo (or gksu) into root or another user (as I sometimes do with sudo -i) I cannot use the display.

I know the risks as root, and this is usually when I want to do something as another user briefly without closing down all the windows in my usual account. With three monitors attached, and 4 workspaces, that can be a lot of windows.

When I try it, however I get something like

```
green@camelot-x:~$ firefox
No protocol specified
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0.0
```

I don't really understand most of that error output (I don't even recognize the name "Mir" -- other than a defunct Russian space station named "peace"), and surely have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: did you try running export DISPLAY=:0 before running your command?

Comment: Yes I did,  with the same result..

Comment: It looked like this: export DISPLAY=:0; gksu -u green firefox

Comment: what if you su to your user... eg `su green` and then `export DISPLAY=:0 && firefox`

Comment: although, thinking about it more... user X should not be able to display onto the screen of user Y....

Comment: Does it work if you just do `sudo - iEu green firefox`? And does `xhost` still work with Mir? Does running `xhost +` and then your command make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me, that for security purposes, user X will not be able to directly display windows on the screen of user Y. You could work around this by sshing to your own computer with x forwarding, as other user and run that program.

Install sshd on your computer:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

X11Forwarding yes must specified in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Then from a terminal:

```
ssh -X green@localhost
```

Then run firefox. It will display in your current session but be run as what ever user you ssh in as.

Comment: BINGO!!  I have disabled passwords in ssh, so I had to put my id_rsa.pub in green's .ssh/authorized_keys, but after that everything was go.